# Apache Web Server , policy agent , openAM

Tags: apache, openam

We have Liferay server and from the login page which is public page configured using policy agent which is on Apache web server ,the  authentication process of the user is been done via openAM.
after succesful validation the user has to be redirected to the goto parameter mentioned in the url and in case of authentication faliure (via authentication module) we are handling the error and redirecting the user to the login page again with the error code in the request.

But now again the apache web server is intercepting the request and I think because of the same there the error codes is been lost, is there's any way to rectify the procedure so that we can have the error codes as well on unsuccessful authentication.

Also in our case the goto parameter is been appended in url more than required number of times which is not correct.

Please let me know where I could be wrong, is that the problem while configuring the policy agent or is the source different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The policy agent will always first look at an existing SSO session tracking cookie... if this does not exist it will redirect the user-agent to the configured loginURL.

If authentication fails no SSO session tracking cookie is available in the request, so you have to put your 'error URL' in the not-enforced list.

You may read the tech overview of OpenSSO (as long as OpenAM does not provide such a doc) to get a basic understanding.